# ¿Cómo coloco bordes para celdas de Excel con PHPSpreadSheet?

Tags: html, array, excel, phpspreadsheet

Hola estoy generando un Excel con PHPSpreadSheet pero no consigo que la celda se genere con bordes verticales

```
$bordes = [
  'borders' => array(
    'outline' => array(
      'borderStyle' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THIN,
      'color' => array('argb' => '000000'),
    ),
  ),
];
```

Cuando lo genero de esta manera el formato que aplica a la celda es este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando me gustaría que solo fueran las verticales las que se pinten, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré el error, lo dejo por acá si a alguien le sirve en alguna ocasión

```
$bordes = [
  'borders' => array(
    'vertical' => array(
      'borderStyle' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THIN,
      'color' => array('argb' => '000000'),
    ),
  ),
];
```

Había que colocar vertical como parámetro, igual todo viene en la documentacion de PHPSpreadSheet